# configure squid to use another digest proxy

Tags: authentication, proxy

I'm connected to a squid proxy that does digest authentication , and I have installed another squid proxy on my centOS 6.4 and configured it to use the upper proxy .

The problem is that I need another PC to connect to my proxy without authentication and that means the authentication must be done in my proxy somewhere in squid.conf

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you further elaborate your question or some sort of figure. As i think it is hard to get what you are trying to achieve

Comment: assume there are two proxies A and B , A is using digest ,
I want to connect B to A "this will need authentication" ,
so any user access to the internet using B will not need authenticating .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.visolve.com/squid/squid24s1/neighbour.php#cache_peer) states that the `cache_peer` configuration command is used to set an "upper proxy", and that command accepts the `login=user:password` option to handle authentication with that upper proxy. Note the following:

- In [HTTP authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617), the client (here, your own proxy) does not know beforehand what kind of authentication the server (here, the upper proxy) requires; if the upper proxy wants to do Digest authentication, it will tell it to your proxy dynamically (with a `WWW-Authenticate` header).
- Your squid proxy must necessarily "know" your password, since it must be able to use it to authenticate with the upper proxy (either by sending it directly, with "Basic" authentication, or by computing hashes over the concatenation of the password and a challenge with "Digest" authentication). This implies that your password will be stored "as is" in the configuration file for your Squid. You'd better protect it correctly. I also encourage you to check whether writing down your password in a file is legally/contractually compatible with the rules which are in force at your organization.
- If you allow "the other PC" to connect to your Squid without authentication, then you may open a door which allows *everybody* to connect to your Squid without authentication. There again, your local sysadmins may frown upon these things. Caution is advised.